# Transaction replication not replicating one column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, database-replication, transactional-replication

One column of type varbinary(200) is not getting replicated to destination table from source table. I have tried updating the column value in main table again but still it is not getting replicated to destination table. Am not seeing any error in replication job and tried running snapshot too. But still no luck. What could be wrong?? Using SQL server 2012.

Replication script for this table: `exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'CWT1200UAT', @article = N'usr_mast', @source_owner = N'dbo', @source_object = N'usr_mast', @type = N'logbased', @description = N'', @creation_script = N'', @pre_creation_cmd = N'drop', @schema_option = 0x000000000803509F, @identityrangemanagementoption = N'none', @destination_table = N'usr_mast', @destination_owner = N'dbo', @status = 24, @vertical_partition = N'false', @ins_cmd = N'CALL [sp_MSins_dbousr_mast]', @del_cmd = N'CALL [sp_MSdel_dbousr_mast]', @upd_cmd = N'SCALL [sp_MSupd_dbousr_mast]'`

Comment: This site is for programming questions, try https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: plz provide more details

Comment: @TheGameiswar: I have a transaction replication between 2 databases. One of the record from a table which is part replication is not getting replicated. Transaction replication is continuous and it is happening without any error. How this record can get missed in replication? Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: you will need to provide more details like ,is this table replicated totally ? or is it replicated based on query? your column seems to be small(with in allowable limit),so is this  something you are replicating  first time or was the column present for a long time and all of a sudden you are seeing issues..you also can script out replication and provide details for that table

Comment: @TheGameiswar: This table was part of replication earlier too, and table is completely replicated. Now I find that replication for this table not happening at all since 2 days. Updating the question with script for this table.

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved after performing following actions:
1. Remove the table which has the issue from replication.
2. Run the snapshot replication and wait for completion.
3. Add back the table into replication.
4. Run the snapshot replication and wait for completion.